# How can I use jQuery to input a vh property instead of px for scrolling nav?

Tags: jquery, css, viewport-units

I am trying to create a nav that fades in after 100vh, but I can only find an example that uses a `px` value instead of `vh`. Is there a way to return a window height value into jQuery to accomplish this? Thanks in advance <3

Instead of 860px, I need it to be equivalent to `100vh`, or equivalent to the height of the window viewport

```
      (function($) {
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $(window).scroll(function(){
              if ($(this).scrollTop() > 860) {
                  $('#navbar').fadeIn(200);
              } else {
                  $('#navbar').fadeOut(200);
              }
          });
      });
  })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible. But vh is defined as percentual height of the viewport. So you can get the viewport height:

```
$(window).height();
```

It will return 860px (in your example) then divide it by 100 and you have how many pixels stand for 1vh unit.

```
var viewportHeight = $(window).height(); // == 100vh
 (function($) {
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $(window).scroll(function(){
              if ($(this).scrollTop() > viewportHeight) {
                  $('#navbar').fadeIn(200);
              } else {
                  $('#navbar').fadeOut(200);
              }
          });
      });
  })(jQuery);
```